# javacript: modify current dom ( not for display )

Tags: javascript

I have a simple page with a content.   I want to catch a dom , modify it before a treatment for a pdf tools.

```
 // keep the id main content 
 let element = document.getElementById('page-content'); 
 // keep element concern button menu for the current dom ( line 1 )
 let div = element.getElementById('menu-zone-button-to-print'); // error
 // add text in the div
 let text = div.createTextNode("This just got added");
 // add div in the current node ( 'div' )
 div.appendChild(text);
```

Error  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null" for the line 2.   I have the id, is correct.
thank for help

Comment: we can not help you like that. Its not clear to us. I think your post is against community guidelines but none the less it could be that your paged-content has not yet been loaded at the time that script is running

Comment: I update my post.    my page is loaded.   I display a page and i active a action to keep a dom, modify it  ( not for display )

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things incorrect about your code

First:
Id property should be unique hence you dont need to search inside `page-content` for your `menu-zone-button-to-print` since its already unique and one exist you can directly search for it like this

```
let div = document.getElementById('menu-zone-button-to-print');
```

if you still want to do so you can do it with querySelector as in the example below

Second:
Stored elements dont have createTextNode in them only document does if im not mistaken
if you want to create an element then you will have to use document.createTextNode like this

```
let text = document.createTextNode("This just got added");
```

and then append the created text to the div like this

```
div.appendChild(text);
```

Below is a working example of your code

```js
var element = document.getElementById('page-content'); 
let div = element.querySelector('#menu-zone-button-to-print');

let text = document.createTextNode("This just got added");
div.appendChild(text);
```

```html
<div id="page-content">

  <div id="menu-zone-button-to-print">
  
    <p> Hello </p>
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```